# Android: Noob problem with a button

Tags: android, button

```
package com.parseador.prueba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //private Button botonParsear;
    private EditText link;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Button botonParsear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotonParsear); 
        //EditText link = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Link);
    }

    public void onParsearClick(View botonParsear) {
     link.setText("Siii");
    }
}
```

Hello.

Ive a problem when i run this code. It keeps FCing. Have tried changing whats on comments, but theres no way to make the button work.

I would appreciate if you could tell me what am i doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Ps: The xml file does have the method on the button. This is its code (on strong the call):

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/parse" 
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:onClick="onParsearClick" 
android:id="@+id/BotonParsear"
```

Comment: post LogCat output, it provides information on the force close. Nobody is going to create a new project and dump your code there just to see the exception...

Comment: Didnt heard about LogCat before. Will be useful anytime in the future. Although i got the solution, thx for your help aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
EditText link = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Link);
```

is almost there. You're declaring a new local variable `link` that shadows the instance variable `link` in your `main` class. So while you assign the local variable to the `View` instance located by `findViewById`, it falls out of scope and ceases to exist after `onCreate` returns. The `link` variable read by `onParsearClick` is still `null` and cannot be dereferenced. Therefore the call to `link.setText` fails.

Change the line so that it is a simple assignment statement rather than a variable declaration:

```
link = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Link);
```

You may want to read up on Java's scoping rules for the future.

Comment: You got it! That was the problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your example(modified) works for me...

```
public void onParsearClick(View botonParsear) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "it is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

See if any of this thread applies to you - [onClick won't fire on ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418282/onclick-wont-fire-on-imageview)

Comment: Thanks for your help aswell. Will take a look at the link anyway.